# Multiple Try Catch in Powershell

Tags: powershell, try-catch

I am trying multiple sources in order to find a file, once I had found the desired file in source 1 for instance, I would like the if statement to move on and not try the other sources. Currently, if the file was found in source 1, Poweshell keeps trying source 2 and source 3 'try-catch' commands.

How do I stop PowerShell from moving forward with the script upon success in source 1 or 2 attempts?

Example:

```
if (a = true){

try
    {
    source 1 
    }

catch [Exception]
    {

    Write-Output "Could not find the file in source 1"
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    }

try
    {
    source 2 
    }

catch [Exception]
    {

    Write-Output "Could not find the file in source 2"
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    }

try
    {
    source 3 
    }

catch [Exception]
    {

    Write-Output "Could not find the file in source 3"
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
    }
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: if this is just a comparison and there is no loop above this you should use `return` as your control flow. `break` may bring unexpected results otherwise: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.3#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, can you please give an example?

Comment: When you say "find a file", are you talking about using `Get-ChildItem` or `Get-Item` with different paths?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thank you for your comment. I mean that I need to run multiple commands based on the same condition, and if for instance, the first try succeeds, I need it to quit the if statement and move forward with the script.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a simple comparison running at script level, then you should use the [`return` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7.3) as your flow control. For example:

```bash
if ($true) {
    try {
        1 / 0
        return
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error 'fail 1'
    }

    try {
        2 / 0
        return
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error 'fail 2'
    }

    try {
        'this works!'
        return
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error 'nothing here'
    }

    try {
        'this doesnt run!'
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error 'nothing here'
    }
}
```

Which would output:

```
Write-Error: fail 1
Write-Error: fail 2
this works!
```

As you can see, the script exits early as soon as one of the try statements didn't fail. Using [`break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.3) shouldn't be an option in this case as it might bring unexpected results. See [Do not use `break` outside of a loop, `switch`, or `trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.3#do-not-use-break-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap).

A simple example of why `break` shouldn't be used outside of those mentioned above, given our `script.ps1`:

```
param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $inputobject)

process {
    if ($inputobject -eq 5) {
        '{0}: {1}' -f $inputobject, $true
        break
    }

    '{0}: {1}' -f $inputobject, $false
}
```

If we were to try a simple pipeline input:

```
PS ..pwsh\> 0..10 | .\script.ps1

0: False
1: False
2: False
3: False
4: False
5: True
```

We would see that **the *whole pipeline* terminates unexpectedly**. If instead we change that `break` to a `return` we can see that the script exits early **but it doesn't terminate the whole pipeline**:

```
PS ..pwsh\> 0..10 | .\script.ps1

0: False
1: False
2: False
3: False
4: False
5: True
6: False
7: False
8: False
9: False
10: False
```